# Cone under similarity transformation

Tags: geometry, transformation, linear-transformations, quadratics, coordinate-systems

Suppose we have a cone passing through the origin of $xyz$ coordinate system. Now, the question is that whether we can find an invertible transformation on this coordinate system that turns the cone into a line or plane, let say on $x'y'z'$ coordinate system? Is the simple argument that a cone consists of infinitely many lines passing through the origin and thus they cannot be packed together and form a line by an invertible transformation true?

Answer (score 1):

For a circular cone, all generating lines have the same angle with the axis of the cone. For an elliptic cone, that angle lies in a range which is maximized for lines lying in one symmetry plane and minimized for the other. Similarity transformations are characterized by preserving angle. A line would be a degenerate cone where all generating lines have angle zero with the axis of symmetry. Conversely, a plane would be a degenerate cone where the minimal angle is $0°$ and the maximal angle is $90°$, in order to stay flat and still cover the whole plane. Neither of these properties can be achieved from a non-degenerate cone while preserving angles.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering this question. Similarity transformation here refers to a transformation matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} P=PP^{-1}=I$; this transformation does not necessarily preserve angle, it preserves angles only in a special case when $P=P^T$. However, we know for sure that any changes in angles and distances will be bounded below and above by a positive constant, since it is an invertible matrix.

Comment: *Any* invertible matrix satisfies $P^{-1}P=PP^{-1}$, so do you mean to say that in your setup, “similarity transformation” is a synonym to “invertible transformation”?

Comment: Yes, precisely, my comment requires an edit in the third line, it should be $P^{-1}=P^T$.